# Double entry for "files" window title on Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, window, 16.10

I am experiencing a strange issue since I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 Yakkety Yak.

I see a duplicated "files" title on my Nautilus windows.

[image: Nautilis menu]

Can anyone tell me why this happens and where I can find a configuration file to fix it ?